# What is equivalent of yarn run flow in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, npm, flowtype

I am familiar with `flow`, and now I want to try out `Typescript`. My main concern is: in `flow` I can run `yarn run flow` to check types, so wanted to know whats the equivalent of it in `Typescript`.

Comment: In typescript it's done with `tsc`. With `--noEmitOnError` it won't emit any JS in case if type check failed.

Comment: Is there any handy command to check types across react/react-native project?

Comment: Have you checked my comment and made any research?

Comment: The command is `tsc --watch` to typecheck and watch for changes. This is assuming you have typescript installed globally. If not, it would be `npx tsc --watch`